# LinkedIn - cannot send messages

Tags: python, message, linkedin-api

I am using Python API for sending messages in LinkedIn.
I found that

```
api.SendMessage("This is a test subject", "This is the test body", [pid])
```

can send messages only to the ones who are in our connected list and not others.

How do you send messages to anyone who is not in our connect list?

Comment: Can you send it outside of API? Please link the api doc as well, code for what you have tried and what error you are getting.

Comment: profile = api.GetProfile(member_id = None, url = <url>")
          print pid, profile.first_name
          result = api.SendMessage("This is a test subject", "This is the test body", [pid])

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-linkedin/

Comment: i am able to send messages only i said is i cannot able to send messages to the ones who are not in my connect list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered elsewhere, this is how LinkedIn behaves, whether you use the API or not. You can only message first degree connections.

There is an InMail feature that allows for messaging outside your first degree network, but that is a paid product. Is that something you're interested in?

Or the other option is to have a person between the sending and recipient agree to "pass the message along." That is not available via the API, however.

That's all I say here, as we're now outside the scope of technical questions.

Comment: ok thanks. but will api work for paid product and i will be avble to send messages using paid product using  python?

Comment: Not today. Can you share what you're working on? Maybe we can get you early access.